# Telerik Reports: only show specific file format in dropdown of file format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am creating a web application in which I have Telerik reporting and user can download those reports, My application is created on asp.net mvc using jQuery for front end,

below is my code for the same

```
@{
    var report = new UriReportSource() { Uri = Model.ReportFileName };
    foreach (var par in Model.Parameters)
    {
        report.Parameters.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.Parameter(par.Key, par.Value));
    }
}

@(Html.TelerikReporting().ReportViewer()
        .Id("reportViewer1")
        .ServiceUrl(Url.Content("~/api/reports"))
        .ReportSource(report)
        .ViewMode(ViewMode.Interactive)
        .ScaleMode(ScaleMode.Specific)
        .Scale(1.0)
        .PersistSession(false)
        .PrintMode(PrintMode.AutoSelect)
)
```

[image]

I Just want to show pdf and excel format in the above dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on report and/or on [application level](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/export-and-configure/configure-the-report-engine/extensions-element).
On report level:

```
Telerik.Reporting.RenderingSettings renderingSettings1 = new Telerik.Reporting.RenderingSettings();
renderingSettings1.Name = "CSV";
renderingSettings1.Visible = false;
this.RuntimeSettings.Add(renderingSettings1);
```

Reference:
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/p-telerik-reporting-report-runtimesettings
https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/export-and-configure/export-formats